# Многопоточное программирование

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Добрый день. При попытке написать код, использующий параллельные вычисления, наткнулся на следующую проблему: при создании нескольких потоков каждый из них выполняет одну и ту же функцию, при этом для каждого потока создается некий объект `task_`. Ниже приведен кусок заголовочного файла с некоторыми произвольными классами: `class_1`, `class_2`, `class_3`. В нем присутствует класс `thread_pool`, который создает нити и сразу запускает на них функцию `worker_thread`.

```
class task_params
{
public:
    float a;
    class_1 b;
    class_2* c;
    task_params::task_params(float a_, class_1 b, class_2* c);
    {
        a = a_;
        b = b_;
        c = c_;
    }
};

class task
{
public:
    class_3* layer = new class_3;
    task_params params;
    void run()
    {
        layer->layer_run(params);
    }
};

class thread_pool
{
public:
    boost::lockfree::queue<task> queue;

    unsigned const thread_count = 2;

    class_3* pool_layer = new class_3;

    vector<thread> threads;

    //конструктор
    thread_pool(class_3* layer_from_main)
    {
            done = false;

            task our_task;

            //////////////
            // Блок заполнения queue данными объекта layer_from_main,
            // передаваемового из вне
            //////////////

            for (unsigned i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
                {
                    threads.push_back(thread(&thread_pool::worker_thread, this));
                }

            for (unsigned i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
                {
                    if (threads[i].joinable())
                    {
                        threads[i].join();
                    }
                }
    }

    void worker_thread()
    {
        task task_;

        while (!done)
        {
            if (queue.pop(task_))
            {

                task_.run();

                /////////////
                // Блок добавления в pool_layer данных из
                // текущего task_.layer
                /////////////

                cout << "thread_run" << endl;
                cout << "thread = " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;

                cout << "adress this task_ : " << &task_ << endl
                    << "adress result from this task_ : " << &task_.layer->states << endl;
                cout << "-----------------" << endl;
            }

            else
            {
                this_thread::yield();
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Необходимые расчеты проводятся в методе `layer_run(params)`, который "запускается" в `task::run(){ layer->layer_run(params) }`. В `layer_run(params)` нити не обращаются к общим данным вообще.

На картинке ниже схематичное изображение процесса запуска нитей:
[Схема `thread_pool`](http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/14/1104/h_1415126696_1701568_b08198684e.jpg)

Сам вопрос заключается в следующем: верно ли, что для каждой нити в цикле в `worker_thread` создается собственный объект `task_`, который используется только данной нитью? Если это так, что подтверждает [Скрин консоли](http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/14/1104/h_1415126741_1886610_c30904ce69.jpg), где выведены `id` нити, адрес `task_`, создаваемого этой нитью, и адрес члена `result` данного `task_`, почему адреса `result` в разных нитях, и соответственно разных `task_`, одинаковые?

И ещё вопрос: если при запуске `task_.run()` в каждой нити, дальше при расчетах нити принципиально не обращаются к общим данным, то верно ли, что никаких "многопоточных" проблем внутри `task_.run()` возникнуть не может?

Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Хм.

[Документация](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html) на lockfree `queue<T>` требует

> * `T` must have a copy constructor
> * `T` must have a trivial assignment operator
> * `T` must have a trivial destructor

Вы их просто не показали, или их в самом деле нету?

Это раз. Затем, в каждом thread'е объект типа `task` **копируется** из экземпляра в очереди. Это то, что вам нужно?

При копировании `task`'а, понятно, копируются данные внутри, если у вас нет конструктора копирования. (Хотя я вместо этого хранил бы в очереди _указатели_ на `task`.)

Comment: @prothet, судя по характерному шрифту и переливам рамки консоли, дело происходит в винде?

Comment: Да, это винда. Компилятор: msvc-12.0. 
 Может быть я ошибаюсь, но, мне казалось всегда, что компилятор создает конструктор копирования автоматически, если не прописан явно какой-либо иной конструктор? То же самое с двумя другими пунктами. Этот класс абсолютно примитивен.
 По поводу указателей - пока намеренно использую копирование при выборе объектов из очереди, чтобы избежать лишних проблем с указателями. Но, конечно, согласен, что очередь с указателями имела бы некоторые преимущества.

Comment: @prothet: Создаёт, это да. Но этот автоматический конструктор копирования может делать не вполне то, что вам нужно. Например, он тупо копирует поля-указатели — это ожидаемое вами поведение? (Кстати, а где в вашем классе `task` поле `result`?)

Comment: `result` я удалил, случайно - хотел максимально упростить код для размещения вопроса.
 Не очень понял, что вы имеете ввиду - мне совсем не важно что будет с объектом задачи после того как я скопирую все его параметры в очередь в виде нового объекта `task_` в очереди.
 Вы думаете стоит попробовать явно прописать нужные для очереди конструктор, оператор и деструктор?

Comment: @prothet: В принципе, если вас устраивает копирование указателей, то проблемы нету. С другой стороны, если вы пропишете явный конструктор копирования, вы сможете отследить, откуда берётся значение `result`.

То есть, судя по всему, те `task`'и, которые добавляются в очередь (этого кода вы не показали), имеют уже одинаковый `result`, и он просто копируется дальше.

Comment: @VladD, `result`, похоже, создается в конструкторе `class_3`, код которого тоже выброшен.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/232/avp , совершенно верно. `result` - это контейнер-map STL.

`class class_3
{
public:
 map< Tcoord, Tstate* >  result;
        ...
        ...
};`

Comment: Кажется, решение нашлось: в `class task { public: class_3* layer = new class_3; ...};` причина. Компилятор каким-то странным образом выделял layer-у один адрес, мне казалось, такого быть не может, даже если инициализация стоит в описании класса.

`class task
{
public:
    class_3* layer = new class_3;
    ...
`

Поменял на: 

`class task
{
public:
    class_3* layer;
    ...
`
При этом сделал инициализацию `layer` каждого `task`, которым заполняется очередь  в блоке заполнения очереди.
Получилось следующее: http://storage8.static.itmages.ru/i/14/1105/h_1415148301_6599298_48fc1152a2.jpg